# Solving $k\log(n) - k\log(k) \leq u$

Tags: equation-solving

How can I persuade *Mathematica* to help me find solutions to the inequality
$k\ln(n) - k\ln(k) \leq u$ over the reals, assuming $u \geq n \geq k \geq 1$.

When I evaluate

```
Reduce[{k*Log[n] - k*Log[k] <= u, u > n, k > 1, n > k}, k, Reals]
```

*Mathematica* can't find a solution. However, $k=2, n=e^2, u = 8$ is a solution, for example.

Comment: What sort of solution do you seek?  `FindInstance` will find any (specified) number of solutions.

Comment: Would something like `Reduce[k Log[Exp[2]] - k Log[k] <= 8, k, Reals]` help ?

Comment: Something in closed form. I don't mind if it has a number of cases.

Comment: As per @MichaelE2 's comment `FindInstance[{k*Log[n] - k*Log[k] <= u, u > n, k > 1, u > k}, {k, n, 
  u}, Reals, 12]` gives 12 solutions.

Comment: I am really looking for something like, if X then $k \leq \frac{\log{u}}{\log{n}}$ etc.

Comment: `RegionPlot[
 k*Log[n] - k*Log[k] <= u && u > n && k > 1 && n > k /. u -> 8, {n, 0,
   10}, {k, 0, 10}]`

Comment: @belisarius  I am really looking for a general closed form solution rather than anything numerical or graphical.

Comment: @Majid That triangle may suggest you somthing ...

Comment: @belisarius's triangle suggested I was misreading the formula.  You can solve it by hand if you divide by `k` and know that `x > Log[x]` (or `n/k > Log[n/k]`).  Forget `FindInstance`.

Comment: `Solve[(n/k)^k == u, k]` will give you a good start: it provides an explicit solution for the boundary.

Comment: @whuber I don't get any real solutions doing that. I get {{k -> -(Log[u]/ProductLog[-(Log[u]/n)])}}

Comment: In what sense is that not a "real solution," Majid?  A plot of this function is not empty.  Using such a plot, for instance, I see that $(u,n,k)=(5,4.5,2.06086)$ is in this form, because all three values are real numbers, $2.06086 = -\frac{\log(u)}{\text{ProductLog}(-\frac{\log(u)}{n})}$, and they satisfy $u\ge n\ge k\ge 1$.

Comment: @whuber I see what you mean. I just meant that the denominator can be a complex number.

Comment: OK, I follow you. But in solving, say, a quadratic equation we take square roots and they can be complex too: does that make the quadratic formula any less useful?  So now you know that $\log(u)\le n/e$ is a necessary condition.

Comment: @whuber Thanks. I am really interested in what $k$ has to be in terms of $n$ and $u$.